# Is deer (venison) prohibited?

Tags: food, non-vegetarian, ahimsa

The ancients hunted deer, presumably for food and not for sport. What is the scriptural evidence that venison should or should not be eaten?

Comment: Rama was hunting deer at the time of Sita's abduction...

Comment: Yes, he is an example of "the ancients (who) hunted deer"

Comment: ancients, normal people or kings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mahābhārata [says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b080.htm) not only can deer be hunted but they can be consumed even without offering them to gods:

> Desirous of benefiting all men, the high-souled Agastya, by the aid of his penances, dedicated, once for all, all wild animals of the deer species to the deities. Hence, there is no longer any necessity of sanctifying those animals for offering them to the deities and the Pitris.

The Critical Edition provides additional context (Bibek Debroy's [translation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XYP75HY)):

> Listen to the ordinances that have been laid down for kshatriyas. **If they eat meat that has been obtained through their own valour, they do not incur any sin. All deer and wild animals are said to have been dedicated to all the gods.** O king! This was done by Agastya in ancient times and that is the reason hunting is praised. There can be no hunting without being prepared to give up one’s own life. O king! There is thus no difference in form between the one who is killing and the one who is being killed. O descendant of the Bharata lineage! That is the reason all the rajarshis went on hunts. The learned say that this does not lead to their being tainted by any sin.

Comment: And, if a family member or friend killed the deer and then offered me its meat, I should accept and consume it, right? Even though it wasn't "obtained by (my) valour.

Comment: I guess so. In Rāmāyaṇa, Rāma-Lakṣmaṇa did the hunting and Sītā just consumed (see [this](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/aranya/sarga47/aranyasans47.htm#Verse22) verse. Here, Sītā is speaking to Rāvaṇa who was in his brāhmaṇa disguise). BTW, [that whole chapter](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b080.htm) in Mahābhārata appears to be promoting vegetarianism :) @RubelliteYakṣī

Comment: From what I've heard vegetarianism came later as a cultural shift. The epics were also written down at a later period. Very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I acknowledge @sv.'s answer on this topic as authoritative.

Here is an additional reference for this issue, from the *Manu Smriti*:

> After death the guilt of one who slays deer for gain is not as (great) as that of him who eats meat for no (sacred) purpose. [[The Laws of Manu, 5](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu05.htm):34]

Comment: Also relevant: "31. 'The consumption of meat (is befitting) for sacrifices,' that is declared to be a rule made by the gods; but to persist (in using it) on other (occasions) is said to be a proceeding worthy of Rakshasas.   

32. He who eats meat, when he honours the gods and manes, commits no sin, whether he has bought it, or himself has killed (the animal), or has received it as a present from others."

Comment: and "56. There is no sin in eating meat, in (drinking) spirituous liquor, and in carnal intercourse, for that is the natural way of created beings, but abstention brings great rewards."